# Lua dissection functions definition

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

This code is part of a Lua dissection script. Could you explain the meaning of this code please , especially the functions

**add_le** and **le_uint**. Thanks

```
    -- Function: Upload functions request
function upload_function_req(buffer, subtree)

  subtree:add_le(buffer(14,2), "func_id:", buffer(14,2):le_uint())
  subtree:add_le(buffer(16,4), "fixed_values:", buffer(16,4):le_uint())
  subtree:add_le(buffer(20,2), "offset:", buffer(20,2):le_uint())
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The function adds 3 fields to the protocol tree.  The `buffer(n,m)` is a [*tvbrange*](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html#lua_class_TvbRange), with `n` indicating the offset into the buffer and `m` indicating the length.  All 3 fields are unsigned integers in little-endian format.  The 1st and 3rd fields are 2-byte integers; the 2nd is a 4 byte integer.  The function does some unnecessary work though and could be simplified like so:

```
function upload_function_req(buffer, subtree)

  subtree:add_le(buffer(14,2), "func_id:")
  subtree:add_le(buffer(16,4), "fixed_values:")
  subtree:add_le(buffer(20,2), "offset:")
end
```

If you want to learn more about the Lua API in Wireshark, you should have a look at the [Wireshark Developer's Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/).  Under [Chapter 11. Wireshark's Lua API Reference Manual](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/wsluarm_modules.html), you will find the relevant sub-chapters.

In particular:

- The `treeitem:add_le()` is described in [11.7.1.3 treeitem:add_le([protofield], [tvbrange], [value],[label])](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tree.html#lua_class_TreeItem).
- The `tvbrange:le_uint()` is described in [11.8.3.3 tvbrange:le_uint()](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html#lua_class_Tvb).

Answer (score 0):

add_le is the same as add, but "le" means little endian, since network protocols uses mostly big endian, changing to "le" can be used in place where little endian is necessary. the same is the int a le_uint (takes bytes from buffer and combines them in to the int according to the big or little endian).